# SwiftUI: Adding item creates gap in NavigationView Lists

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a list which normally gets formatted nicely. When I update the array items and re-add the the element it introduces a big space in the list, adding additional height to some rows.

Here is the list:

[image]

Click the add button and the new item is added with additional height:

[image]

The strange thing is that if you play "track and field" with the add button and hit it many times quickly everything works OK.

Here is some code that demonstrates the problem:

```
import SwiftUI

var newIndex = 0

var newItems = ["Echo", "Tango", "Hotel", "Alpha", "November", "Kilo", "Yankee", "Oscar", "Uniform", "Indigo", "Romeo", "Whisky", "Lima", "Victor", "Charlie", "Foxtrot", "Delta", "Xray", "Papa", "Juliet", "Bravo", "Golf", "Quebec", "Mike", "Sierra", "Zulu"]

struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var mainList:[String] = ["Echo", "Tango", "Hotel", "Alpha", "November", "Kilo", "Yankee", "Oscar", "Uniform", "Indigo", "Romeo", "Whisky", "Lima", "Victor", "Charlie", "Foxtrot", "Delta", "Xray", "Papa", "Juliet", "Bravo", "Golf", "Quebec", "Mike", "Sierra", "Zulu"].sorted()
    @State var selectedItem:String? = "Echo"
    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            List()
            {
                ForEach(mainList, id: \.self)
                {item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item), tag: item, selection: $selectedItem, label:
                    {
                        Text("\(item)")
                    })

                 }
            }
        }
        .toolbar
        {
            Button(action: {addNewItem()})
            {
                Label("Select", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
            }
          }
    }
    
    func addNewItem()
    {
        if newIndex == newItems.count
        {
            newIndex = 0
        }
        let item = newItems[newIndex]
        if mainList.contains(item)
        {
            mainList = mainList.filter({ $0 != item })
        }
        mainList.append(item)
        selectedItem = item
        newIndex += 1
    }
    
}

struct DetailView: View
{
    @State var item: String

    var body: some View
    {
        Text(item)
    }
}
```

I have found that in this case it is caused by the filter command, but I have seen this behaviour in many of my lists across my apps. I assume it is caused  by removing and adding things to the same list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite a bug in Xcode Beta 1, 2 / macOS 12 Beta 1. The thing is, you use `String` itself as ID, which means if two strings are the same, they'll be treated as one item in `List`:

```swift
ForEach(mainList, id: \.self)
```

This may be what you want. However, in function `addNewItem()`, there comes:

```swift
mainList = mainList.filter({ $0 != item })
// ...
mainList.append(item)
```

A same item can be removed and appended. So the `List` will re-calculate the height, and **move** the same item from where it was to the bottom, which causes a bug.

One not perfect solution is that you can wrap the item in a struct which provides an explicit ID, like this:

```swift
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    let value: String
    // Other properties in the future...
}
```

And each time you want to add a new item, a copy will be created:

```swift
items = items.filter { $0.value != item }
        
let newItem = Item(value: item)
items.append(newItem)
```

In this way, `List` won't see the old and the new as the same item and produce moving animation. Full code:

```swift
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    let value: String
    // Other properties in the future...
}

var nextItemIndex = 0
let itemsRow = ["Echo", "Tango", "Hotel", "Alpha", "November", "Kilo", "Yankee", "Oscar", "Uniform", "Indigo", "Romeo", "Whisky", "Lima", "Victor", "Charlie", "Foxtrot", "Delta", "Xray", "Papa", "Juliet", "Bravo", "Golf", "Quebec", "Mike", "Sierra", "Zulu"]

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items: [Item] = itemsRow.sorted().map { Item(value: $0) }
    @State private var selected: UUID?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(value: item.value),
                                   tag: item.id, selection: $selected) {
                        Text(item.value)
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button(action: addNewItem) {
                Label("Select", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    private func addNewItem() {
        let item = itemsRow[nextItemIndex]
        nextItemIndex = (nextItemIndex + 1) % itemsRow.count
        
        items = items.filter { $0.value != item }
        
        let newItem = Item(value: item)
        items.append(newItem)
        
        selected = newItem.id
    }
}
```

Let's see if it'll be fixed in the next macOS Beta.

**UPDATE: It's fixed on macOS 12 Beta 3. Now you don't have to make a copy.**

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Text("\(item)").fixedSize()
```

and attach the .toolbar to the List not the NavigationView.

Comment: That did fix it in a way, but my actual code requires a multi-variable height row not a single line fixed row height. Although it fixed this simple example it didn't actually fix my underlying problem.